# Can't figure out HTML file path formatting

Tags: python, html, pandas, win32com

I am trying to send a link to a location on our servers via email, but I can't get the HTML portion of the link to work.

This is my file path--   P:\2. Corps\PNL_Daily_Report

What I've tried--

```
newMail.HTMLBody ='<a href="file://///P:\2.%20Corps\PNL_Daily_Report">Link Anchor</a>'
newMail.HTMLBody ='<a href="P:\2. Corps\PNL_Daily_Report">Link Anchor</a>'
newMail.HTMLBody ='<a href="P:\2.%20Corps\PNL_Daily_Report">Link Anchor</a>'
```

Obviously I am not an HTML guy, so i bet this answer will be quick for someone who is. Any ideas on how to get the HTML link to format?

Comment: Then...do you want send links inside body' eMail?

Comment: yes, I am sending it via outlook win32com

Comment: is the P drive on the local machine or the server?

Comment: Everyone receiving the email has a network drive mapped to "P:"? I'd think you'd want to serve that file via web server, or as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) on MSDN Blog, your `href` should be:

```
<a href="file:///P:/2.%20Corps/PNL_Daily_Report">Link Anchor</a>
```

Windows path is a significant break from UNIX-style path, and the internet mostly uses Unix convention.

- `file://` indicate the scheme (the other popular schemes are `http://` and `ftp://`)
- `P:` refers to the drive, or the mounting point in Unix's file systems
- `/` means root, or the ultimate point that refers to a file system
- The backward slash (`\`) is the Windows' path separator, but Unix's is the forward slash (`/`)